# Out-of-tree kernel module won't load

Tags: kernel-modules, modprobe

I'm trying to get an out-of-tree kernel module working. The module is the `usbtm` module from Epson for their TM-70/TM-70II slip printers and the TM-S1000 cheque reader.

(The code is GPL licensed, so if you want to copy of the source, let me know, and I will share it.)

I have successfully built the module, and installed it, but it won't load:

```
root@GAU288888LD06 ~ # uname -rm
5.11.0-27-generic x86_64

root@GAU288888LD06 ~ # modinfo /lib/modules/5.11.0-27-generic/extra/usbtm.ko 
filename:       /lib/modules/5.11.0-27-generic/extra/usbtm.ko
description:    EPSON USB POS Printer Driver Version 3.4 for Linux Kernel 2.6
author:         EPSON Edge, Toronto
license:        GPL
srcversion:     CAC308CD474255ABD4753E1
alias:          usb:v04B8p0202d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
name:           usbtm
vermagic:       5.11.0-27-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

root@GAU288888LD06 ~ # modprobe usbtm
modprobe: FATAL: Module usbtm not found in directory /lib/modules/5.11.0-27-generic
```

I don't see any error in `dmesg`.

Any ideas how to debug this and get it working?

(Incase you are wondering why I don't use the in-tree `usblp` module, this doesn't work for the cheque reader, only for the slip printers.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`modprobe` doesn’t know about your module, which suggests that you need to run

```
depmod
```

to re-generate `modules.dep.bin`.

See [man depmod](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/depmod.8.html)